# How can I delete all lines containing non-standard English letters using Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have an English word list that needs some fixing.

There are some words that contain an apostrophe and some words that contain accented letters and so on and so forth.

I don't know all of the non-standard English letters used in the word list, so I want to be safe and just remove all lines containing non-standard English letters.

How can I do this using Notepad++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Ctrl+ H to bring up the Replace dialog
2. In `Find what`, enter: `^.*[^a-zA-Z\n\s]+.*$`
3. In `Replace with,` enter: `\n` or leave it blank
4. Check: `Regular expression` option at the end
5. Click `replace all`

Comment: This will only remove [^a-zA-Z] chars though, you should capture the line that contains this chars.

Comment: That is true. Please see the updated answer! Tested, guarantee to replace a line with special characters replaced

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung Perfect! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean everything except ascii? If so, try:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```

[image]

Comment: An apostrophe (') and accented letters (e.g, À) are ASCII

Comment: @NguyenDoanTung - yes but you should try the regex. E.g. this regex matches `À` (**extended ASCII**), but not the apostrophe. Screenshot updated just for you. ;)